# How to get nice, smooth transitions in an Illustrator gradient mesh?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient-mesh

I am needing help understanding what is happening with my gradient mesh colors. I'm trying to create some folds in a scarf using the mesh, however, when I apply the darker color I get a weird lighter grey transition color.

[image: Gradient Mesh Problem Graphic]

I've tried searching Google for a solution, but I haven't found anyone with a similar problem. Does anyone here know what might be causing this or if there is a way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using spot colors? What is the color of the outer mesh color stops?

Comment: Ah! I was using spot colors. I changed them to process and now they are working correctly. Thanks! (is there some way for me to mark this as the correct answer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Spot colors, you may get these halos. To prevent them, ensure **all** mesh points are the **same** spot color and then merely a **tint** of that color.

By default, when you add a new mesh point it gets converted the the document color mode (CMYK/RGB). Illustrator has difficulty blending RGB/CMYK to Spot, so you get halos.... but as long as you blend from/to **tints of the same spot color** you should be okay. So, basically, you have to add a mesh point, reset the color to the spot and adjust the tint.. then you have to go edit all the auto-added mesh points and ensure *they* are the same spot color and adjust their tint.... repeat for each new mesh point.

Alternatively, you can create the mesh with CMYK/RGB colors, if possible.

Comment: This explains why I was able to use spot colors on a couple of other mesh objects. They were all single color items and I just used tints (saved as separate swatches) to add highlights. Thanks!